# Не работает секундомер (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Добрый день, буду рад, если вы мне поможете.

При нажатии на кнопку 'Start' секундомер начинает идти, однако при нажатии на 'STOP', он не останавливается.

Каждому ответившему плюс в карму ;)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
```

class Timer extends Component {

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        stop: false,
        numb: 0
    }
    this.startTimer = this.startTimer.bind(this)
    this.stopTimer = this.stopTimer.bind(this)
}


startTimer() {

    let timer = setInterval(() => {
        this.setState({numb: this.state.numb + 1})
    }, 1000)

   // this.stopTimer(timer)

   this.state.stop ? this.stopTimer(timer) : null

  }

stopTimer (timer) {
    this.setState({stop: !this.state.stop})
    clearInterval(timer)
}



render() {
  return (


    <div className='timer'>
        <div className="timerNumber">{this.state.numb}</div>
        <div className="flex">
            <input onClick={this.startTimer} value='GO' type="button"/>
            <input onClick={this.stopTimer} value='STOP' type="button"/></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

}

export default Timer;

Answer (score 1):

При вызове stopTimer , не передаешь timer

Советую хранить в его в this и при вызове stopTimer  делать 
clearInterval(this.timer)